# execute a method of an function class inside another method of that class

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have this two methods :

```
Cluster.prototype.initiate_xhr_request = function(url, callback) {
    var self = this,
        request = (Modernizr.test_xmlhttprequest) ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState === 4) {
            switch(request.status) {
                case 200:
                    callback.apply(request,[ request.statusText ]);
                    break;
                case 400:
                    callback.apply(request,[ request.statusText ]);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            };
        } else 
            console.log('An error occured during the XHR request');
        }
    };
    request.open("HEAD", url, false);
    request.send();
};

Cluster.prototype.operations = {
    '&&': function(array){ 
        return array.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
             return previousValue && currentValue;
         })
     },
    '||' : function(array){
        return array.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
            return this.initiate_xhr_request(previousValue) || currentValue;
        })}
};
```

**EDIT :** The methods are invoked as it follows :

```
Cluster.prototype.calculate = function(operation, array){
    return this.operations[operation](array);
};

/* call the calculate function */

this.calculate('&&', some_array);
```

Obviously, this line `this.initiate_xhr_request(previousValue)` won't work. I kept trying to find a good solution of doing what I'm trying to do there, but I couldn't find one (: Is there a way of doing that and keeping the structure I have the same ?

Comment: Where/how are the `"&&"` and `"||"` methods invoked?

Comment: @user1689607 ~ just added an example (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.call` or `.apply` to manually set the `this` value of the method you're invoking.

Here I set the `this` value of `this.operations[operation]` to that in the current lexical environment. *(Using `.apply` instead of `.call` would do the same, but would take your `array` and pass its members as individual args, which you don't seem to want.)*

```
Cluster.prototype.calculate = function(operation, array){
    return this.operations[operation].call(this, array);
};
```

---

Now in those methods,  the `this` value will be what you expect, except that you need to make sure the `this` value is retained in then `.reduce()` callback for the `"||"` method.

The classic way to do that is to keep a variable reference to the outer lexical environment, an reference that variable in the callback:

```
Cluster.prototype.operations = {
    '&&' : ...,
    '||' : function(array){
        var self = this;
        return array.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
            return self.initiate_xhr_request(previousValue) || currentValue;
        })}
};
```

But a more modern way is to use `Function.prototype.bind` to create a new function with the `this` value manually bound:

```
Cluster.prototype.operations = {
    '&&' : ...,
    '||' : function(array){
        return array.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, index, array){
            return this.initiate_xhr_request(previousValue) || currentValue;
        }.bind(this))}
};
```

Comment: bind doesnt work in a lot of browsers , so beware. self = this is a more portable solution.

Comment: @camus: True, but neither does `.reduce`, so I'm guessing modern environments are targeted, or there's already shims applied.

Comment: btw is there a fallback or polyfill for .reduce() in browsers like IE8 or less ?

Comment: @Roland: Mozilla Developer Network has polyfills. Just Google *"MDN Array.prototype.reduce"*, and you'll find the relevant MDN page. Unfortunately I've noticed minor errors in many of their Array polyfills, so I would double check it against the spec, and make corrections as needed

Comment: thanks (: sounds fair ... I will check the code before using it ... but I had no idea they post code with issues ...

Comment: @Roland: Unfortunately it's a wiki format. Most of the errors I've noted are minor, but real... for example they way they handle the optional `context` argument for most Array methods will produce a result different from the spec in some cases. In the case of `.reduce`, there is no `context` argument, but it doesn't handle a sparse Array properly for the first iteration. I've looked through revision history of some of the shims, and have seen that many used to be implemented correctly. Because of this, I won't spend the time to fix them, because my fixes may just be overwritten later.